# ICEfaces pieChart: how to change the slice color?

Tags: jsf, icefaces, icefaces-3

I am using ICEfaces 3.2. I want to know how to change the color of the ICEfaces ace pieChart slices.

My JSF code is as below:

```
<ace:chart id="chart" value="#{piechartbean.pieData}"
  animated="true"  legend="true"
  widgetVar="pieChart"/>
```

I want to provide my own color for each slices of the pie chart. My bean code is as below:

```
public List<SectorSeries> getPieData() {
  SectorSeries series = new SectorSeries();
  series.add("PENDING", map.get("PENDING"));
  series.add("SUBMITTED", map.get("SUBMITTED"));
  series.add("ARCHIVED", map.get("ARCHIVED"));
  series.setShowDataLabels(true);
  series.setSliceMargin(4);
  series.setFill(true);
  pieData.add(series) ;
  return pieData;
}
```

Comment: Don't they have `seriesColors` attribute in `<ace:chart` like in primefaces (after all they did took primefaces library as is...) http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/pieChart.html

Comment: NO.  seriesColors attribute is not there in the tld. I really dont know if there is any other attribute in ace:chart for color

Comment: Can anyone please help  :(

Comment: Shame IceFaces docs are broken , http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/ace/tld/ace/chart.html ask on their forum to fix it with a proper page , You might get some usefull info there...

Comment: SectorSeries is a subclass of ChartSeries which has the property String[] seriesColors. This can be used to define an array of CSS color definitions for use by the renderer. This solution i got from Icesoft forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SectorSeries is a subclass of ChartSeries which has the property String[] seriesColors. This can be used to define an array of CSS color definitions for use by the renderer. This solution i got from Icesoft forum.